# Scraping webpage using Python and Requests Package

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am looking to scrape a certain number from a website.

When inspecting in chrome I see the following div I want to pull:

```
<div class="sc-18nh1jk-0 bTfoun css-1p6fq9y">2472.38</div>
```

This class name looks weird to me.  Here is the code simple code I use to try and pull the '2472.38' number:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

r = requests.get('MYWEBSITE')
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
CurrentPrice = tree.xpath('//div[@class="sc-18nh1jk-0 bTfoun css-1p6fq9y"]')
print(CurrentPrice)
```

output is: []

Any suggestions? Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: *"This class name looks weird to me."* That's because there are three classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you provided the websites url it would have been nice, but I think that this webpage you are trying to scrape is using generated class names which means that the class will be dynamic.

Comment: Yes, that is true, the class is dynamic.
How to address this?

Thanks for your response